# How to search Mongo for element in a list of string using spring query

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data

So, here's my mongo entity :

```
public class OfferEntity {

@Id
private String id;

public List<String> categories;
private Type type;
private String title;
}
```

I use spring  org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria and  org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query.

The goal is to find Offers by categories.

Something like :

```
        Query query = new Query();
        ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

        strings.add("new");
        strings.add("old");
        strings.add("blue");
        strings.add("stolen");
       
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("categories").contains(strings);
```

or

```
      query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("categories").contains("new","old","blue");
```

I know there's no such thing as "contains" method here, but you get the idea.
I've found some things about "elemMatch" but it does not seems to match my need, as it's meant to find a element in an array with a matching key/value pair.

Any thoughts ? I'm sure it's possible but I'm a bit lost here.

Comment: What is Categories in mongo? an array? I think you are looking for [Criteria.In](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Criteria.html#in-java.lang.Object...-)

Comment: Categories is an array in mongo.
I think the "all" operator is more appropriate, but the trick is that I can't use a list as parameter in 
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("categories).all(*a list of categories*)

My goal is to get all offers where "categories" contains every element of my list. 

if my list is "old, blue" I want all offers who are old AND blue (regardless if they're old or new)

Comment: You have two different questions. You need to combine $or and $and. Were you Able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Criteria.in`

[Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Criteria.html#in-java.lang.Object...-)

```
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("categories").in(Arrays.asList("new","old","blue"));
```